# Skip blank lines when iterating through file line by line

Tags: bash

I am iterating through a file line by line and put each word into a array and that works.  But it also picks up blank lines and puts it as an item in the array, how can I skip the blank lines?

example file

```
      Line 1
line 2

line 3
        line 4 

line 5
   line 6
```

My code

```
while read line ; do
            myarray[$index]="$line"
            index=$(($index+1))
    done < $inputfile
```

Possible psuedo code

```
while read line ; do
           if (line != space);then
            myarray[$index]="$line"
             fi
            index=$(($index+1))
    done < $inputfile
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the blank lines first with `sed`.

```
for word in `sed '/^$/d' $inputfile`; do
    myarray[$index]="$word"
    index=$(($index+1))
done
```

Answer (score 42):

Be more elegant:

```
echo "\na\nb\n\nc" | grep -v "^$"

cat $file | grep -v "^$" | next transformations...
```

Comment: Why the `cat` to `grep`?  Wouldn't `grep -v "^$" "$inputfile"` do just as well?

Comment: Since the output is meant to be piped to another operation, it's nicer to pipe in the input file than to supply it as an argument. That way, you can read the data flow straight from left to right, rather than start-in-the-middle-go-left-then-jump-right. Admittedly, it wastes 4 characters and a few milliseconds, but I don't think that's a big deal. 

Also, presenting it this way makes it easy to just swap out the first stage of the pipeline if the input is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: `$file` should really be double-quoted here. There's no guarantee the filename won't contain spaces.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the OP would actually use this answer. Substitute the last line for `$inputfile`?

Comment: "be more elegant" and `cat ... | grep` are generally considered contradictory (since "elegant" is itself subjective); `cat` to `grep` is generally considered poor form. If you want to achieve the goal of simply putting the input file first, the same can be achieved without the extra process via `< "$file" grep "pattern..." | cmd | ...`

Comment: the `echo "\na\nb\n\nc"` is probably confusing in this example, as `echo` doesn't handle control chars by default (but it depends on which `echo` you're using: the shell-built-in, or one found in the `$PATH`); since we're talking `bash`, a better example would be: `printf '\na\nb\n\nc' | grep -v '^$'` (or equivalently, `... | grep '.'`

Comment: The question asks to skip blank lines, not empty lines, so `grep -v "^\s*$"` is more precise.

Answer (score 29):

Implement the same test as in your pseudo-code:

```
while read line; do
    if [ -n "$line" ]; then
        myarray[$index]="$line"
        index=$(($index+1))
    fi
done < $inputfile
```

The `-n` test means `true if not empty`.

You can also use expressions like `[ "x$line" = x ]` or `test "x$line" = x` to test if the line is empty.

However, any line which contains whitespace **will not** be considered empty. If that is a problem, you can use `sed` to remove such lines from the input (including empty lines), before they are passed to the `while` loop, as in:

```
sed '/^[ \t]*$/d' $inputfile | while read line; do
    myarray[$index]="$line"
    index=$(($index+1))
done
```

Comment: It could be simply: `if [ "$line" ]; then`

Comment: yes, that works on Linux/bash... not sure about other / older Unix and shells. The autoconf tools specifically use the `test "x$line" = x` form for max. portability.

Comment: Could I add something to sed?  If there is a blank space before  the first letter in a line to remove that space or spaces up to the first letter in the line?

Comment: well, you could use: `sed -e '/^[ \t]*$/d' -e 's/^[ \t]*//'` to delete blank or all whitespace lines **and** to remove all leading whitespace before non-whitespace in a line.

Comment: Copy your code up top, is that correct?  I'm not getting good results.

Comment: well, if you run just the `sed` part, you'll see it does the right thing.

Comment: Just don't worry about the leading whitespace. The shell completely ignores it after the command substitution.

Comment: Yeah it outputs but the loop doesn't capture in your above code with sed.

Comment: the loop does, insert an `echo $line` and you'll see. I think your problem is that `myarray` is local to the loop and not visible outside the loop.

Answer (score 5):

`cat -b -s file |grep -v '^$'`

I know it's solved but, I needed to output numbered lines while ignoring empty lines, so I thought of putting it right here in case someone needs it. :)

Comment: as an alternative to `cat` (which reformats the output more than one typically wants), `grep` can also add line numbers. If matching every line, no numbers are skipped: e.g., `grep -v '^$' file | grep -n .` (you can convert the colon (`:`) to something else via `sed`)

Answer (score 3):

Use grep to remove the blank lines:

```
for word in $(cat ${inputfile} | grep -v "^$"); do
   myarray[$index]="${word}"
   index=$(($index+1))
done
```

Comment: Why the `cat` to `grep`?  Wouldn't `grep -v "^$" "$inputfile"` do just as well?

Comment: Both are correct. I just used to use 'cat' because sometimes I need to use 'echo' instead 'cat'.

Answer (score 2):

This version is very fast compared to solutions that invoke external commands like `sed` and `grep`. Also it skips lines that contain only spaces, the lines don't need to be empty to be skipped.

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=()
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ [^[:space:]] ]]; then
        myarray+=("${line}")
    fi
done < test.txt

for((i = 0; i < ${#myarray[@]}; ++i))
do
    echo ${myarray[$i]}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I've been doing it. Doesn't require calling grep, and you don't need to have two levels of indentation either.

```bash
while read line; do
 # skip  empty lines
 [ -z "$line" ] && continue
 echo "processing $line"
done < "$inputfile"
```